IDX10104: TokenLifetimeInMinutes must be greater than zero. value: '-3152398' (Parameter 'value')
I am facing an issue with reading the 2FA code in my application because the token is getting expired. The specific error in the event viewer logs is:
IDX10104: TokenLifetimeInMinutes must be greater than zero. value: '-3152398' (Parameter 'value')

Which indicated that "TokenLifetimeInMinutes must be greater than zero" and currently my "TokenLifetimeInMinutes" is set to be in seconds as this:
 "TokenLifetimeInMinutes": {
    "Time": 189180000
  }

This value (189180000 seconds) is equivalent to 52550 hours. The error occurs in my code at the following lines:
var expiration = response.Data.SessionExpirationDate.Value.ToUniversalTime();

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
{
    TokenLifetimeInMinutes = (int)expiration.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes + 1
};

where var expiration value is:
response.Data.SessionExpirationDate = response.Data.SessionExpirationDate.Value.AddSeconds(-webExpirationTimeSettings.Time);

and "webExpirationTimeSettings" is derived from
public class WebExpirationTimeSettings
{
    public int Time { get; set; }
}

and declared as a variable in the service
//persistent login
private readonly WebExpirationTimeSettings webExpirationTimeSettings;
How can I resolve the issue where the token expiration time is set incorrectly, leading to a negative TokenLifetimeInMinutes.

You haven't provided sufficient details for anyone to help you. Where is your code? Is this for OAuth? OIDC? Where's the stack-trace? Etc?

What were you doing? Which system are you using? Is it something to do with Active Directory??

Please check if the server time is synchronized? It seems that your token has expired after it was generated.

And you also need to share the settings of  TokenValidationParameters  with us, many thanks

"TokenLifetimeInMinutes": { "Time": 189180000 } is ridiculously high, even if it wasn't causing any problems. In most applications an access-token should have a lifetime between 5 minutes and 24 hours (and many people will argue even 24 hours is too long).

What is webExpirationTimeSettings.Time ?

Hi Raju, could you kindly check my sample code for testing?

I still strongly suggest you to check whether the system time of each servers are correct?
